# What are parts of html like "src=" called?

Tags: html

Elements, attributes, or...? I'm pretty ignorant and it'd be faster to learn if I knew what they were. To be clear, I don't mean the image that follows src, but src itself. Thanks for your time.

Comment: attribute, and you could find that reading any decent starter book or tutorial.

Comment: See the [MDN glossary entry for attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Attribute) (with links to further documentation). Would not recomment W3Schools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered in the [the HTML syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#syntax) section of the HTML specification. You can see the definition of [attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attributes) there:

> Attributes for an element are expressed inside the element’s start tag.

It goes on to provide more detail with examples.